# function that return query result

Tags: php, mysql

assume that i have a table named *mytable* with columns:

```
------------------------
| id | field1 | field2 |
------------------------
```

and assume i have a html files:

```
<body>
<?php 
    include ('connect-db.php');
    include ('function.php');
?>

<ul>
    <?php 
        myfunction();

        while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            echo "<li>".$row['field1']." and ". $row[field2]."</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
</body>
```

this is my `connect-db.php` file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$dbname     = "dbname";

$conn=new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
?>
```

and this is my `function.php` file:

```
<?php
    function myfunction(){
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
        $result = $conn->query($sql);
    }
?>
```

How to echo the field1 and field 2? because i have and error

Comment: provide your error please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any variable used inside a function is by default limited to the local
>   function scope.

You can read more about it here: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). How to fix it? Pass the `$conn` as an argument of `myfunction`, and return the `$result`.

```
function myfunction(mysqli $conn) {
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
    return $conn->query($sql);
}
```

then you can call it with

```
$result = myfunction($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the following changes.....

at main page

```
  <body>
  <?php 
      include ('connect-db.php');
      include ('function.php');
  ?>

  <ul>
      <?php 
         $result= myfunction();

          while($row  = $result->fetch_assoc()){
              echo "<li>".$row['field1']." and ". $row[field2]."</li>";
          }
      ?>
  </ul>
  </body>
```

At your function file..

```
      <?php
      include ('connect-db.php');
      function myfunction(){
          $sql    = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
          $result = $conn->query($sql);
          return $result;
      }
  ?>
```

Comment: In main page you have to define the variable that must be catch the returned result from function.

Comment: In function page you have to include the database connection file to query with database...these are common mistakes....